# Can not use ubuntu-mono font in chakra-UI

Tags: reactjs, fonts, chakra-ui

I'm trying to use the ubuntu-mono font in react with chakra-UI. So, I referred to the chakra-UI [docs][1].
However, the change could not be reflected.
My ```theme.ts``` and ```App.tsx``` are below.

`theme.ts`

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
    fonts: {
        heading: "Ubuntu-mono",
        body: "Ubuntu-mono",
    },
    styles: {
        global: {
            body: {
                backgroundColor: "black",
                color: "white",
            }
        }
    }
})

export default theme;
```

`App.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
    ChakraProvider, Container,
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import theme from "./theme/theme";
import '@fontsource/ubuntu-mono/700.css';

import {Router} from "./router/Router";

export const App = () => (
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Router/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ChakraProvider>
)
```

Of course, I have run `npm install` with the `package.json` that includes the `"@fontsource/ubuntu-mono": "^4.5.6"` line in its `dependencies`.
I also referred to another [doc](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theming/customize-theme) of the chakra-UI, however, I could not find out describes regarding this problem.

Although, this may an easy problem, anyone who gives me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this has to do with the environment. I tried it initially in CodeSandbox but the font didn't load but when I ran it locally using Vite app, it worked just fine.

What environment are you working in? See my repo here: https://github.com/estheragbaje/test-fonts

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I could find the solution in your repo.
I typed the font name "ubuntu-mono" in theme.ts, however, the correct string is "Ubuntu mono"("-" is needless).
Why are there different strings for font settings between package.json and theme.ts?("Ubuntu-mono" in package.json, on the other hand, "Ubuntu mono" in typescript code.)
Anyway, your post helped me. Thank you!!